# Cannot getText from EditText in AlertDialog that has setView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I made a custom XML layout file, in there I have an EditText.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/length"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:hint="Vibration time(ms)"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In another activity, I made an `AlertDialog`, then I `setView` to this layout. It was successful and I see `EditText` in the `AlertDialog`.
But the problem is, when I do this:

```
EditText edittext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.length);
int time=Integer.parseInt(edittext.getText().toString());
```

An error happens and say

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
```

I don't know why it says null object because I gave `EditText` an ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `findViewById` in alert dialog view

```
 ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(android.R.id.content);

    View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.my_dialog, viewGroup, false);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setView(dialogView);

    EditText edittext=dialogView.findViewById(R.id.length);
    int time=Integer.parseInt(edittext.getText().toString());

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: What does the `ViewGroup` there do?

Answer (score 0):

do it like this

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

.
.

EditText edittext=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.length);


dialog.show();
```

Comment: I am using AlertDialog

Comment: I think it is the same just write dialog. before findViewById

Comment: No, still `NullPointerException`